# ubuntu 15.10 and pecl_http 1.7.6

Tags: php

I tired to install pecl_http in version 1.7.6

but I'm getting error when is trying to complete installation

```
sudo pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6

downloading pecl_http-1.7.6.tgz ...
Starting to download pecl_http-1.7.6.tgz (174,722 bytes)
.....................................done: 174,722 bytes
71 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
whether to enable cURL HTTP requests; specify libcurl directory [yes] : 
whether to enable support for gzencoded/deflated message bodies; specify zlib directory [yes] : 
whether to enable response content type guessing; specify libmagic directory [no] : 
whether to depend on extensions which have been built shared [yes] : 
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root5axpu9/pecl_http-1.7.6
running: /tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/configure --with-http-curl-requests --with-http-zlib-compression --with-http-magic-mime=no --with-http-shared-deps
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20131226
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable extended HTTP support... yes, shared
checking whether to depend on extensions which have been built shared... yes
checking whether to enable cURL HTTP request support... yes
checking whether to enable libevent support fur cURL... yes
checking whether to enable zlib encodings support... yes
checking whether to enable response content type guessing... no
checking for egrep... (cached) /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for getdomainname... yes
checking for getservbyport... yes
checking for getservbyname... yes
checking for zlib.h... found in /usr
checking for zlib version >= 1.2.0.4... 1.2.8
checking for curl/curl.h... found in /usr
checking for curl-config... found: /usr/bin/curl-config
checking for curl version >= 7.12.3... 7.43.0
checking for SSL support in libcurl... yes
checking for openssl support in libcurl... no
checking for gnutls support in libcurl... no
checking for bundled SSL CA info... /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
checking for curl_share_strerror in -lcurl... yes
checking for curl_multi_strerror in -lcurl... yes
checking for curl_easy_strerror in -lcurl... yes
checking for curl_easy_reset in -lcurl... yes
checking for curl_formget in -lcurl... yes
checking for curl_multi_setopt in -lcurl... yes
checking for curl_multi_timeout in -lcurl... yes
checking for ext/event support... PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
no
checking for event.h... found in /usr
checking for libevent version, roughly... 1.4 or greater
checking for libcurl version >= 7.16.0... 7.43.0
checking for curl_multi_socket_action in -lcurl... yes
checking for ext/hash support... PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
yes
checking for php_hash.h... /usr/include/php5/ext/hash
checking for ext/iconv support... PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
yes
checking for ext/session support... PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
yes
checking whether to add a dependency on ext/hash... yes
checking whether to add a dependency on ext/iconv... yes
checking whether to add a dependency on ext/session... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root5axpu9/pecl_http-1.7.6/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root5axpu9/pecl_http-1.7.6/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root5axpu9/pecl_http-1.7.6/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/php5/ext/hash  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/missing.c -o missing.lo
```

.......

```
Makefile:203: recipe for target 'http_api.lo' failed
make: *** [http_api.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Does any one has any idea what to check?

Comment: Please give the entire output of your commands.

Comment: I'm running `sudo pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6` and getting above results with error

`Makefile:203: recipe for target 'http_api.lo' failed
make: *** [http_api.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed`

Comment: I am asking you to provide the entire output, not just some bits of it which may or may not be relevant.

Comment: Here you have
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b56d5bac5d007079f949

Answer (score 0):

According to the full output this is outdated extension that hasn't been updated to recent PHP internals.  You might try compiling the extension with PHP 5.4, but I would rather abandon it completely as it seems unmaitained and it might contain various other bugs.